# Why it's not possible to run wget with background option in slurm script?

Tags: bash, wget, slurm

I used this script for downloading files. Without `-b`, `wget` download files one by one. With `-b`, I have the possibility to download files in background but also simultaneously. Unfortunately, the script doesn't work in SLURM. It only works without `-b` in Slurm.

**Script for downloading files**

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir data
cd data
for i in 11 08 15 26 ;
do
  wget -c -b -q ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR116/0${i}/SRR116802${i}/SRR116802${i}_1.fastq.gz 
  wget -c -b -q ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR116/0${i}/SRR116802${i}/SRR116802${i}_2.fastq.gz
done

cd ..
```

**Slurm Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=mytestjob     # create a short name for your job
#SBATCH --nodes=2                # node count
#SBATCH --ntasks=2               # total number of tasks across all nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2        # cpu-cores per task (>1 if multi-threaded tasks)
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4G         # memory per cpu-core (4G is default
#SBATCH --time=10:01:00          # total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --array=1-2              # job array with index values 1, 2

#Execution

bash download.sh
```

**On the terminal** : `sbatch slurmsript.sh` ( It dosen't work) `no jobid`

Comment: @Rachid K. Thanks for editing the markdown text.

Comment: Why not use `wget -cq <url> &` to run each `wget` command in the background?

Comment: I tried this solution, in this case I had two files at the same time but not all files simultaneously, I mean that i had the execution of two `wget` but for one item.exp SRR....215_1.fastq.gz and SRR...215_2.fastq.gz without SRR208 ,  SRR211 etc.

Comment: Any error when you submit the job with sbatch? Or any other errors at any point?

Comment: No, not any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can download multiple files at the same time with `curl`.

In your case, this should work:

```sh
# Create an empty bash array of urls.
urls=()

# Add each url to the array, such that '-O' and the url are separate
# items in the array. This is necessary so that the curl command will
# look like 'curl -O <url1> -O <url2> ...', since the -O command must
# be provided for each url.
for i in 11 08 15 16; do
    urls+=( "-O" "ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR116/0${i}/SRR116802${i}/SRR116802${i}_1.fastq.gz" )
    urls+=( "-O" "ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/SRR116/0${i}/SRR116802${i}/SRR116802${i}_2.fastq.gz" )
done

# Simultaneously download from all urls.
curl --silent -C - "${urls[@]}"
```

To explain each of the `curl` options:

- `--silent` is the equivalent of `wget`'s `-q`. Disables `curl`'s progress meter.
- `-C -` is the equivalent of `wget`'s `-c`. It tells `curl` to automatically find out where/how to resume a transfer.
- `-O` tells `curl` to to write the output to a file with the same name as the remote file (this is the behavior of `wget`). This must be specified for each url.

Alternatively, you might want to consider installing and using [`aria2`](https://github.com/aria2/aria2).

Comment: Thank your for this proposition but unfortunately, this script running with slurm, allows to download files one by one and not simultaneously.